# MultiCheckBoxWidget rendered as In-Out-Widget

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

We have the following Dexterity schema:

```
from plone.app.form.widgets import MultiCheckBoxWidget

visibilityVocabulary = SimpleVocabulary(
[
    SimpleTerm(u'OSP', title=u'OSP'),
    SimpleTerm(u'BIZ', title=u'BIZ'),
]

class ISomeSchema(Interface):
     # ...
     form.widget(visibility=MultiCheckBoxWidget)
     visibility = schema.Set(title=Visibility',
                             value_type=schema.Choice(vocabulary=visibilityVocabulary)
                             )
```

The field is rendered using an In-And-Out Widget instead of using checkboxes
as specified inside our schema.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Widgets in `plone.app.form` are for `zope.formlib` forms. Dexterity uses the `z3c.form` form library.

Try `z3c.form.browser.checkbox.CheckBoxFieldWidget` instead. Like this:

```
from zope import schema
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleVocabulary
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleTerm

from plone.directives import form

from z3c.form.browser.checkbox import CheckBoxFieldWidget

visibilityVocabulary = SimpleVocabulary(
[
    SimpleTerm(u'OSP', title=u'OSP'),
    SimpleTerm(u'BIZ', title=u'BIZ'),
])

class ISomeSchema(form.Schema):

     form.widget(visibility=CheckBoxFieldWidget)
     visibility = schema.Set(
             title=u'Visibility',
             value_type=schema.Choice(vocabulary=visibilityVocabulary)
         )
```

Comment: That does not make a difference.